# I can't set NSDate property to nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I am trying to set an `NSDate` property to `nil`, but it keeps the value it already has.

The property is on an object that is being presented from a `UIViewController`.

In FirstViewController, I am doing something like this:

```
SecondViewController *_secondViewController;

_secondVC.myObject = myObject;
```

In the SecondViewController, I am doing something like this:

```
myObject.dateProperty = nil;
```

I can set the dateProperty to another date, but when I try to set it to `nil`, it keeps the value that was passed from the FirstViewController.

I have tried this in the SecondViewController:

```
NSDate *dateAsNil;

myObject.dateProperty = dateAsNil;
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Edit:

Answering rikh:

The above code is my actual code with variable names changed.

I am typing

```
po myObject.dateProperty
```

and it is displaying the prior date of `July 22, 2016`.

Also the textfield that is displaying it shows the prior date.

When the user taps on a button "Cancel"
We format the date and return a string with the method

```
[DateFrmt formateDate:(NSDate *)];

_editLabel.text = [DateFrmt formatDate:myObject.dateProperty];
```

Comment: " it keeps the value that was passed from the FirstViewController." How have you reached that conclusion? How are you examining/displaying the value? And show your actual code, not something like it

Comment: I think you mean answering @DonaldTrumpatemyhamster

Comment: You haven't shown enough code, only a very brief condensed version that doesn't show enough about the controllers and their relation. For example in the first view controller you have not actually created a second view controller in the code you have shown, how is the second view controller created?

Comment: You are only declaring a SecondViewController in the code you have shown, you are not creating one. So where and how does it get created?